# Start and run apache Tika in docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, apache-tika, tika-server

I want to install and run apache tika in a docker container in order to do that I need to specify all of that inside a docker file , how to do that exactly ?

Comment: What's wrong with the docker file that Apache Tika provides?

Comment: Hi,I did not found the docker file your mention ?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/tika-docker and https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/tika

Comment: Ah no I need to create my won Dockerfile and specify tika as dependency not using an already built image